# Why can't I create a numpy array like this: array([1, 2], 3)

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import array
test_list = [[1,2],3]
x = array(test_list) #ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Basically, I have a point with 2 coordinates and a scale and I was trying to put several on a ndarray but I can't do it right now. I could just use [1,2,3] but I'm curious about why I can't store that type of list in an array.

Comment: Please don't use list as a variable name.

Comment: oh sorry i was using "list" in my native language and when i translated it i didn't even realize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing because the array is non-rectangular. If we change the `3` to `[3, 4]` then it works.

```
>>> array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: @pnodbnda Numpy only supports rectangular (NxM) arrays. Yours is not rectangular as the lower-right element is missing.

Comment: also, the data in an *array* must be homogeneous.  if your element types are `list` and `int`, that's not homogeneous.  if you changed the `dtype` to `py_object` it would work because they'd be of the homogeneous type `object`.  that's the fundamental distinction -- lists are inhomogeneous, arrays are homogeneous.  if you want to store inhomogeneous data types, use a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
x = array([[1,2],3], dtype=object_)
```

which gives you a an array with a generic "object" dtype. But that doesn't get you very far. Even if you did

```
x = array([array([1,2]),3], dtype=object_)
```

you would have x[0] be an array, but you still couldn't index x[0,0], you'd have to do x[0][0].

It's a shame; there are places where it would be useful to do things like this and then do x.sum(1) and get [3, 3] as the result. (You can always do map(sum, x).)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need non-rectangular arrays, you can give `awkward` a try:

```py
In [1]: import awkward

In [2]: test_list = [[1,2],3]

In [3]: x = awkward.fromiter(test_list) 

In [4]: x
Out[4]: <UnionArray [[1 2] 3] at 0x7f69c087c390>

In [5]: x + 1
Out[5]: <UnionArray [[2 3] 4] at 0x7f69c08075c0>

In [6]: x[0]
Out[6]: array([1, 2])

In [7]: x[0, 1]
Out[7]: 2
```

It behaves in many ways like a `numpy` array.