# How to insert numpy 1D array to numpy 3D array?

Tags: python, numpy, insert

So I've got a 3-dimensional numpy array and I want to insert into it a 1-dimensional numpy array. How can I do it?

For example, this is my 3D array and I want to insert [2,2,2]

```py
[[[1,1,1],
  [3,3,3],
  [4,4,4]],
 [[5,5,5],
  [6,6,6],
  [7,7,7]]]
```

so it looks like this:

```
[[[1,1,1],
  [2,2,2],
  [3,3,3],
  [4,4,4]],
 [[5,5,5],
  [6,6,6],
  [7,7,7]]]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Something's missing - the row between the 5s and 6s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with standard numpy arrays as they must remain **rectangular**. Potentially, [you could create one with `dtype=object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523432/why-cant-i-create-a-numpy-array-like-this-array1-2-3), but this seems to me like you would lose the efficiency of `numpy`.

Maybe you are better off with regular lists?

```
l = [[[1,1,1],
      [3,3,3],
      [4,4,4]],
     [[5,5,5],
      [6,6,6],
      [7,7,7]]]
l[0].insert(1, [2,2,2])
```

which modifies `l` to:

```
l = [[[1,1,1],
      [2,2,2],
      [3,3,3],
      [4,4,4]],
     [[5,5,5],
      [6,6,6],
      [7,7,7]]]
```

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks